# Sphinx - Making the engine give greater weight to the title column & better part matches

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

Really this is two questions.. but related

1) How would I give a 'greater' weight to phrases that are in the title column/index?

2) How to prevent part matches - eg if I searched for "art" it would ignore words like "part", "cart" etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) setFieldWeights() API function is for that.

2) You dont get part matches by default. You must have done something to enable them - something with min_prefix_len and/or min_infix_len. If you do want infix matches sometimes look at enable_star option.

Comment: you are awesome :)
you should build a stackoverflow dedicated to sphinx!! :D

Comment: Well there is a dedicated sphinx forum, which works quite well http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/forum.html?id=1 :)